# Delegate not working, data isn't being passed to view controller from selecting cell

Tags: swift, uikit

I have a movie app that fetches an API and I'm trying to get set the movie image on the other view controller when I click on the cell. But the delegate is coming back as nil and nothing is happening.

If anyone knows how to fix this please help me out!

***Movie Library VC***

```
protocol LibraryVCDelegate {
    func didGetMovie(moive: String)
}
  
var movieDelegate: LibraryVCDelegate!


//Movie tapped, prints out the movie URL Image

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let movieName = dataSource.itemIdentifier(for: indexPath) else {
            return
        }
   
        movieDelegate.didGetMovie(moive: movieName.image.original)
        print(movieName.image.original)
        let detailsVC = DetailsViewController()
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: detailsVC)
        
        present(navController, animated: true)
    }
```

***Movie DetailsVC***

```
// View did load I'm getting the delegate
    
let librayVC = LibraryVC()
librayVC.movieDelegate = self

//
extension DetailsViewController: LibraryVCDelegate {
    func didGetMovie(moive: String) {
        
        movieImage.image = UIImage(named: moive)
    }
}
```

Receiving nil and data isn't being passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally we should create protocol functions on ViewController B and should pass any updated UI value via delegates to ViewController A. For example consider LibraryVC as A, DetailsVC as B. So you need define protocols on DetailsVC like below,

```
protocol DetailsVCDelegate: AnyObject {
   func didGetMovie(movie: String)
}
```

Then declare delegate variable.

```
weak var delegate: DetailsVCDelegate?
```

Then triggered it where you need it.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    delegate?.didGetMovie(movie: movieName.image.original)
}
```

But before you defined that protocol function on ViewController A.

```
extension LibraryViewController: DetailsVCDelegate {
func didGetMovie(movie: String) {
    movieImage.image = UIImage(named: moive)
}
}
```

And you should assign power during your navigation process on ViewController A as LibraryVC,

```
let details = DetailsVC()
details.delegate = self
```

This the proper way of passing any values between two view controllers. But in your case seems in your code, I think you want to update movies name on DetailsViewController instead of library view controller. So you should pass data by creating custom initialiser on DetailsViewController.

```
class DetailsViewController: UIViewController {
    
var imageName: String?

// this is a convenient way to create this view controller without a imageName
convenience init() {
    self.init(imageName: nil)
}

init(image: String?) {
    self.imageName = imageName
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

// if this view controller is loaded from a storyboard, imageName will be nil

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    movieImage.image = UIImage(named: self.imageName)
}
```